# Calling a postgres function from ef core succeeds but returns 0 results

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a database table which saves the information for the nodes of a file tree structure. I also have a database function that takes a string path as input and finds if the path exists in the tree or not and returns the id of the last node of the path.

The requirement is to get the id of the node (leaf node) if it exists from the database.

My function is as follows -

```
-- FUNCTION: main.find_node(character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS main.find_node(character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main.find_node(
    _path character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    var_folder_current character varying;
    var_parent integer := 1;
    c text;
BEGIN
    drop table if exists tmp_table;
    create temp table tmp_table (
        id integer
    );
    RAISE NOTICE '_Inside main.find_node';
    FOR c IN SELECT unnest(string_to_array(_path, '/'))
    LOOP
        SELECT INTO var_parent main.get_node(c, var_parent);
        RAISE NOTICE 'node: %', c;
        RAISE NOTICE 'parent: %', var_parent;
        IF var_parent = -1
        THEN
            EXIT;
            --RETURN -1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    insert into tmp_table(id) values (var_parent);
    return query select n.id from main.nodes n where n.id = var_parent;
    --RETURN var_parent;
END;
$BODY$;
```

If I execute this function directly in the database as -

```
select * from main.find_node('x/docs/addnewproj.png')
```

I get the following result -

```
"id"
1890184
```

But when I call the same db function from c#, I get 0 results -

```
        public bool FileExists(long id, string bucket, string path)
        {
            var exists = false;
            if (id != -1)
            {
                exists = FileIdExists(id);
            }
            else
            {
                exists = FilePathExists(bucket, path);
                if (!exists)
                {
                    var x = _dbContext.nodes.Where(n => n.id == 1890184);
                    var existing_node = _dbContext.nodes.FromSqlRaw("select * from main.find_node('{0}')", path);
                    if (existing_node != null)
                        exists = true;
                }
            }
            return exists;
        }
```

If I directly query the value (returned after successful execution in db), I get results. But the **existing_node** value is always empty.

My main.nodes table looks like -

```
-- Table: main.nodes

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main.nodes;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main.nodes
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    type integer NOT NULL,
    active boolean NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE main.case_insensitive_collation NOT NULL,
    inherits_permissions boolean NOT NULL,
    insert_by text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    insert_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    update_by text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    update_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_nodes" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the Node.cs class -

```
    public class Node
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public NodeType type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool active { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public bool inherits_permissions { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string insert_by { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime insert_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string update_by { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime update_date { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int size { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int size_limit { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Neha

Comment: `_dbContext.nodes.FromSqlRaw(...).ToList()` ?

Comment: yes I tried that too, but it is still empty